# extract list from list and delete first and last quote - Python

Tags: python, list, quote

I have the following list of lists in Python:

```
[['CATEGORIA KO,FABRICANTE,MARCA,PRESENTACION,SEGMENTO,TIPO,Z FABRICANTESC,Z 
MARCA SC,Z TOTAL SC'],
[REVIEWED,CATEGORIA KO,FABRICANTE']]
```

I want to extract each list like this:

```
['CATEGORIA KO','FABRICANTE','MARCA','PRESENTACION','SEGMENTO','TIPO','Z 
 FABRICANTESC','Z MARCA SC','Z TOTAL SC']

['REVIEWED','CATEGORIA KO','FABRICANTE']
```

However, I do not know how to delete that very first and last quote that the original lists have.

Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: `lst = [i[0].split(",") for i in lst]`?

Comment: Thanks!!! This worked fine!!!!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach. `str.split` by comma

**Ex:**

```
lst = [['CATEGORIA KO,FABRICANTE,MARCA,PRESENTACION,SEGMENTO,TIPO,Z FABRICANTESC,ZMARCA SC,Z TOTAL SC'],['REVIEWED,CATEGORIA KO,FABRICANTE']]
lst = [i[0].split(",") for i in lst]
print(lst)
```

**Output:**

```
[['CATEGORIA KO', 'FABRICANTE', 'MARCA', 'PRESENTACION', 'SEGMENTO', 'TIPO', 'Z FABRICANTESC', 'ZMARCA SC', 'Z TOTAL SC'], ['REVIEWED', 'CATEGORIA KO', 'FABRICANTE']]
```